# Skip a getView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I currently have a custom listview in Android that I generate by overriding the getView method of ArrayAdapter. It works perfectly. However, in certain cases I need to "skip" an item in the list. I tried returning null, but that just gives a nullpointer error. So my question is, what can I return in getView, so that no new item is added to the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom Filter.

If you have a custom ArrayAdapter you can implement a custom filter and it will filter your  list by a certain criteria and then those items won't even show and won't call getView to begin with.

If this sounds like it would work for you and want some more information or example code let me know.

Comment: How would you set that up (just an overview)

Comment: You override a couple methods in the adapter, have the adapter implement Filterable, and create a class that extends Filter.  Then, you call the filter, it filters based on whatever criteria you setup in your subclassed filter on a thread and then updates the list when it has finished.  The Filter has two methods, one does the filtering on a thread and the other publishes the results.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the visibility property of your item to View.GONE? That should do it.
If there is a better way to do it, I don't know it

Comment: Actually not. It creates blank places in the list.